# Why html overflow-x:hidden affects the back to top button script?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Because of
`html { overflow-x: hidden; }`
the *vanish at top* part of back to top button script doesn't work.

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script> <!-- Include jQuery -->

    <button onclick="topFunction()" class="buton" id="myBtn" title="Go to top"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-up"></i>

        <script>
    let mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    
    window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
    
    function scrollFunction() {
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        mybutton.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        mybutton.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    
    function topFunction() {
      document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
      document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
    }
            </script>
            </button>

CSS


    html,
    body {
    height: 100%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

body {
    background-color:#060606;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.buton {
  overflow-x: visible !important;
}
  
#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: 20px; 
  right: 30px; 
  z-index: 99; 
  border: none; 
outline: none;
  background-color: red; 
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 18px; 
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #333; 
}
```

mostly code please add more details mostly code please add more details mostly code please add more details mostly code please add more details mostly code please add more details mostly code please add more details mostly code please add more details mostly code please add more details mostly code please add more details

If i cut out overflow-x in html, the button will vanish at top, but there will be space in the right part of the whole website content

Comment: So for this, you can either specify a class for your back to top button and overwrite that overflow-x or you can maybe make a class for your main page instead of using html as a universal tag.

Comment: Why include jQuery (and the tag) if you're not going to use it? Also, just make the button into `<a href="#" class="button">....</a>` and style it like a button.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to override that `overflow-x` style and select your element by `id`.
CSS:

```
#myBtn {
  overflow-x: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: `.buton {
  overflow-x: visible !important;
}`  with html,body {overflow-x:hidden}, button doesn't show up at all

Comment: Do you have the button absolutely positioned? or is it just somewhere on your page

Comment: If you could update this question with your CSS for the specific elements that would take out a lot of the guess work.

Comment: Also you don't appear to have a class "```buton```" associated with your button. Also may be helpful to spell it *"button"*

Comment: sorry thats button in my language, thats the css and i modified the html with the class